# Equivalence between regular expressions

Tags: regex, regular-language, automata, dfa

I have two different regular expressions:

(1) ($ + b)a*(b + bba*)*
($ is the empty language)

(2) b*(a + bb + bbb)*b*

I want to demonstrate that both expressions are equivalent, but I don't know how. I have two ideas on mind, but I don't know how to implement them.

1. Convert both expressions to a DFA. Then minimize both DFA's and check if they are the same. I think that this option is the most formal but I don't know how to get it. I know how to go from a DFA to its regular expression using Arden's Lemma, but not the inverse.
2. Simplify both expressions to make them equal. I have tried to simplify both of them using common factor for example, but I can't make them equal.

Answer (score 0):

(2) requires a lot of rewrite and equivalence rules for you to guarantee this in the general case. Of course, if you're just trying to do this for these two specific regex's, then you can work ad hoc.

(1) is, however, the "real" way to do it. I'm surprised you know how to use Arden's lemma, but not the reverse direction, which is *far more common* (in textbooks and practice) and easier. Literally any formal language book or any compiler book will give you at least one algorithm to map a regex to a DFA and also to minimize a DFA. In the event you don't have access to such books, I point you to two article I wrote ages ago, each presenting a taxonomy (at that time comprehensive) of algorithms, one for mapping a regex to a DFA and the other for minimising a DFA:
http://www.kornai.com/EFS/OnlineSupportMaterial/Watson/Papers/constax.600dpi.ps
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2247379_A_Taxonomy_of_Finite_Automata_Minimization_Algorithms

Lastly, more comprehensive work is in my own phd called "Taxonomies and Toolkits of Regular Language Algorithms", from 1995.

BTW, I should also mention there are many toolkits implementing these algorithms, in a variety of languages.

Best regards, Bruce

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 seems better to me, probably because I'd have no idea how to feasibly accomplish Option 2. I would recommend this:

1. construct a DFA M1 such that L(M1) = ($ + b)a*(b + bba*)*
2. construct a DFA M2 such that L(M2) = b*(a + bb + bbb)*b*
3. construct a DFA M12 such that L(M12) = L(M1) \ L(M2)
4. construct a DFA M21 such that L(M21) = L(M2) \ L(M1)
5. the regular expressions describe the same language iff L(M12) and L(M21) are both empty

To see whether a DFA M accepts the empty language, you can:

1. construct M' by minimizing M
2. see whether M' accepts the empty language by checking if the initial state is empty and has all transitions initiating in the initial state terminating in the initial state

To minimize a DFA, you can start by listing each pair of states of the DFA. Then, cross out any pair where one state in the pair is accepting and the other is not. Then, iteratively, cross out any pair (q, q') where q goes to some state p on symbol s, q' goes to some state p' on symbol s, and (q, q') is already crossed out. Continue until no more pairs of states can be crossed out. At this point, any pairs not crossed out represent equivalent states in the input automaton and can be combined in the minimal automaton. This is just one method. Other methods are available.

```
q    s    q'
q0   a    q1
q0   b    q2
q1   a    q1
q1   b    q3
q2   a    q2
q2   b    q3
q3   a    q3
q3   b    q0
```

Here, `q0` is initial and `q3` is accepting. We try the first algorithm:

```
    q0    q0    q0    q1    q1    q2
    q1    q2    q3    q2    q3    q3
#   --    --    --    --    --    --
1               XX          XX    XX   // q0,q1,q2 are not accepting; q3 is
2   XX    XX                           // on input b these go to q2,q3
3                                      // can't cross out q1,q2 by any rule
```

We find that q1 and q2 are equivalent and can be combined to give the following equivalent DFA:

```
q    s    q'
q0   a    q12
q0   b    q12
q12  a    q12
q12  b    q3
q3   a    q3
q3   b    q0
```

The way to construct an automaton from a regular expression is the following:

1. if r = x, where x is some string over the language's alphabet, then an NFA for r can be constructed by adding one initial state and one additional state for each symbol of x; then, make the last of these states accepting;
2. if r = st, and M and M' are NFAs for s and t, then an NFA for r can be constructed by changing all of M's accepting states to non-accepting while adding lambda-transitions to the formerly initial state of M', which is no longer initial.
3. if r = s+t and M and M' are NFAs for s and t, then an NFA for r can be constructed by adding a new initial state with lambda transitions to the formerly initial states of M and M', which are no longer initial;
4. if r = s* and M is an NFA for s, then an NFA for r can be constructed by adding a new accepting initial state with lambda transition to the formerly initial state of M while adding lambda transitions from the formerly accepting states of M to this new initial state.

Once you have an NFA for the regular expression, you can determinize it using the powerset or subset construction. To do this, create a DFA which has one state for each subset of the NFA's set of states. Then, add a transition from subset X to subset Y if input symbol s takes the NFA from state x to state y, where x is in X and y is in Y. Note: you can remove lambda-transitions first if it helps you to think about it, or use the convention that if s takes the NFA from q to q' and there is a lambda transition from q' to q'', then s also takes the NFA from q to q''. The initial state is the one containing only the initial state of the NFA; all states containing an accepting state are accepting.

This gets you through steps 1 and 2. At this point, it might be helpful to minimize according to the suggestion given for step 5. Next, use the Cartesian product machine construction to find DFAs for the differences (or just construct one machine for the symmetric difference and save a step). Each state in the product machine will correspond to a pair of states, one taken from the first input machine, and the other taken from the second input machine. Then, add transitions in the product machine which take the DFA from state (x, y) to state (x', y') wherever there are simultaneously transitions from x to x' in the first machine, and from y to y' in the second machine. The initial state is the one corresponding to the pair of initial states in the input machines; the accepting states are those which (for difference) have x accepting and y not accepting (for symmetric difference, they are those which have either x accepting or y accepting but not both).